# Adding an extension to C with clang

Tags: llvm-clang

I'm trying to add support for a C dialect in clang which adds syntax to put extra information into llvm's metadata, but I can't wrap my head around how the parsing system works. Is there documentation somewhere for clang's parsing system and how it handles different languages?

Ideally I would like to make additional functions to handle the Tokens I've defined similarly to how the ObjectiveC handlers work, but I can't figure out how the C-ObjectiveC distinction is made in the Parser.